# Does RSTP also maintain correct mac table entries?

Tags: mac-address, ieee-802.1w

I've got 4 switches connected in a circle and they all run RSTP. Lets assume the following:

```
switch A (root bridge) ------- switch D
       |                              |
       |                              | <= that link is the alternate path
       |                              |
switch B --------------------- switch C
```

Now to avoid a L2-loop, one link between two switches will be in a blocking state, that port would have the alternate role on one side (that link is between switch C and D). Now when I disconnect the link between A and B, the link between C and D immediately becomes "active" and I've got what I wannted - in the last test I had 2 ping losses, which is ok I'd say. BUT: when I re-establish the link between A and B again, my network goes down for approx 30-40 sec and I can't access devices on switch B from switch A (sounds like traditional STP, but RSTP is configured).

So my question now points to the mac-address-tables: Having a fast convergence (without timers) according to RSTP and avoiding loops (and therefore broadcast storms and mac-address-flapping) is one thing, updating the mac-address-table is another thing. I'd say it isn't enough to enable the link between A and B and to put the link between C and D into the discarding state, because switch A and D need to update their mac address table to make sure that the frames are sent into the anti-clockwise-direction instead of sending frames into the direction of switch C when accessing devices connected to port B.

I've googled a lot, but I have never found any hints or topics regarding the RSTP synchronization in combination with the the mac-address-table update. So the real question is: Are mac-address-tables upgraded when there are topology changes in RSTP or is that not part of RSTP?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've found the issue here, it was a bug in the firmware. Everything's working perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: Tangential to the main question but - just because you have configured RSTP, doesn't mean you aren't running in STP compatibility mode.

Comment: correct @richardb, that's why we have Wireshark ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the real question is: Are mac-address-tables upgraded when there are topology changes in RSTP?

Yes.  MAC address tables are flushed for the port that receives the topology change notice.

> BUT: when I re-establish the link between A and B again, my network goes down for approx 30-40 sec and I can't access devices on switch B from switch A (sounds like traditional STP, but RSTP is configured).

That does sound suspiciously like STP.  Perhaps you have a misconfiguration somewhere.  If you post your switch configurations, we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is a very helpful answer. But please let me ask a further question: You write "MAC address tables are flushed for the port that receives the topology change notice" - you mean all MAC's from that port or all MACs of that switch holding the port? How is a fast transition of a route achieved when there are no ARP replys after the synchronization? I mean a machine behind B is still not known from A when the MAC tables are flushed and no ARPs are sent...

Comment: Unknown MAC addresses are flooded out all ports.

Comment: ok, so if we apply that information to the example above, which port/switch would flood all unknown macs and via which protocol? arp or is it sent within the bpdu?

Comment: I think you're confusing differing functions.  MAC flooding has nothing to do with RSTP.  ARP is a layer 3 protocol and has nothing to do with the switching (bridging) function.  (R)STP just determines whether a port is forwarding or not).  If a switch receives a unknown destination MAC, for example, from a host, it will flood it.

Comment: ah, got it, had a little knot in my mind. Last question: When you say that mac address tables are flushed for ports taht received topology changes, does switch A also receive a topology change from switch D in the example above? In other words: does A also do a flush of the mac address table? I assume: yes, it does. correct?

Comment: Yes.  The TC is sent on all designated and root ports